# Logical stuck in my project

Tags: java, netbeans

Since I got my previous question about arrayoutofbounds error resolves but downvoted (no hard feelings :D but it was my first question so you should expect some "mistakes"). Anyway i gonna try one more time with a new question. It is a project-exercise that I had on my exams for Programming II lab lesson. Firstly it requires a class called Point which describes a point in 2d space with x and y coordinates (piece of cake).

Morever, it requires a class called Line (a line in general consists of 2 points in 2-d space) (does this mean necessarily that class Line inherits class Point?) and describes a line in 2-d space with 2 points (piece of cake also). In addition, it requires a method called void MoveLine(Point, Point) which will move the line (and here starts the stuck :D).

Finally it requires creating a main class with 3 objects A, B, C as Points (using the 2 constructors in class Point) and then print the info of  Point B on screen. After that it requires creating 2 objects D, E as Lines and initializing Line D with 0 values and Line E with Points A and B. To continue with, it requires to print Line E's info on screen (so far so good) but then it wants us to move the Line E in a way that it crosses Point (1,1) which will be point c. And here is my problem lying. At the end it wants us to print the new info of Line E on screen. Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Below is the full code I created so far, in order to avoid confusions like the ones in my previous question.

```
public class Point {
    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    public Point() {
        //First constructor-no arguments
    }

    public Point(double x1, double y1) {
        //Second constructor-2 arguments
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }

    public void setX(int x1) {
        x = x1;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(int y1) {
        y = y1;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "("+x+","+y+")";
    }
}
```

Class Line

```
public class Line extends Point{
    private Point pStart;
    private Point pEnd;

    public Line() {
        //First constructor-no arguments
    }

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        //Second constructor-2 arguments
        pStart = p1;
        pEnd = p2;
    }

    public void setStartPoint(Point p1) {
        pStart = p1;
    }

    public Point getStartPoint() {
        return pStart;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(Point p2) {
        pEnd = p2;
    }

    public Point getEndPoint() {
        return pEnd;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Line's start point: "+pStart.toString()+"\t"+"Line's end point:    "+pEnd.toString();
    }

    public void MoveLine(Point p, Point mp) {
        //My problem :D 
        p.x += mp.x;
        p.y += mp.y;
    }
}
```

The main class

```
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point A = new Point();
        Point B = new Point(4,5);
        Point C = new Point(1,1);
        Point zeroStartPoint = new Point(0,0);
        Point zeroEndPoint = new Point(0,0);

        A.setX(8);
        A.setY(13);

        System.out.println("Point B: "+B.toString());

        Line D = new Line();
        Line E = new Line(A,B);

        D.setStartPoint(zeroStartPoint);
        D.setEndPoint(zeroEndPoint);

        System.out.println("Line E: "+"\n"+E.toString());

         MoveLine(E.pStart,);   //WTF? my problem no.2

        System.out.println("Line E: "+"\n"+E.toString());

        /* As you can see my problem is more about logic 
           and less about programming. Any ideas? */
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time reading this. I am looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To avoid getting close votes, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk cheers m8 i have checked it. I know i was not so specific in my previous post but I think this is a match improve question in terms of clearence and specification :)

Comment: @Kosmas, don't mind the downvotes, you'll get there where you want to be eventually. Back to your question, just extend the length of line E, in such a way that it includes point (1,1).

Comment: It's a requirement that `Line` extends `Point`?

Comment: Does it say in the assignment that `Line` should extend `Point`? It seems more like a `Line` should be composed of `Point` instances. A `Line` is not a `Point`.

Comment: Also, the intent of `MoveLine` is not clear given that it takes two `Points`. What's the post-condition? Is it just supposed to set the endpoints to the passed parameters? Are you sure it's not supposed to take either a single `Point` or two `doubles`?

Comment: @jerry No, it says that a line in general consists of 2 points in the 2-d space. But does that mean that class Line inherits class Point? (gonna edit 1st, first for the notice)

Comment: It will help a lot if you *clearly* ask a specific question.

Comment: Then you should only use composition (which you're already doing in addition to inheritance). What benefit are you hoping to see by extending `Point`?

Comment: @jerry About the method MoveLine the task says that it takes 2 arguments (Point, Point), but the implementation is mine and i am not sure if i have approached it the right way.

Comment: Forgot to mention that at the very bottom it says that we should show within our code that we make use of the object-oriented properties of the language (isn't inheritance on of them?)

Comment: @Kosmas It would be much easier if you can tell what exactly is asked from `MoveLine(Point, Point)`. Also *we should show within our code that we make use of the object-oriented properties of the language* doesn't mean you must use the concept even if it is wrong.

Comment: @Ashish As i said at my original post the `MoveLine(Point, Point)` is needed in order to move the line in the 2-d space

Comment: Is it move line to new `(Point, Point)`? Is it move `pStart` by 1st `Point` and `pEnd` by 2nd `Point` in which case, using `Point` to represent `(dX,dY)` is bad design choice?

Comment: @Ashish I guess it is about moving it so that there are new Points in start of line and end of line. As for your second question i think it is what i implement in my method but hey i am stuck so i may be wrong :D

Comment: Supposing that the two `Point` arguments are the new start and end points of our line, how do we calculate the coordinates of these two `Points`

Comment: I came up with this thanks to @terry post about gradient :)
    
    `public void MoveLine(Point np1, Point np2) {
        double g = (np2.getY()-np1.getY())/(np2.getX()-np1.getX());
        
        pStart.y = (g*np1.getX())-1;
        pStart.x = (np1.getY()+1)/g;
        pEnd.y = (g*np2.getX())-1;
        pEnd.x = (np2.getY()+1)/g;
    }`
And in main class

    `E.MoveLine(E.getStartPoint(), E.getEndPoint());`

Comment: Kosmos, a couple issues. First, the code you suggested won't make `E` pass through `(1,1)`, it will end up with endpoints `(8,15)` and `(4,7)`. You've also got the potential for a divided by zero if `np2.getX() == np1.getX()`. Also, be aware that the way you're constructing `Line` objects, any subsequent changes to the points you passed will be reflected in the line. Lastly, if you believe the intent of `MoveLine` is to make its parameters the new start and end points, you're code doesn't do that. It should be much easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, one very easy way to move line E to include (i.e. cross) point (1, 1) would be to change **either** pStart or pEnd to be equal to (1,1).

Comment: That was what i tried to do at first but if i am right, that does not require us to use the MoveLine method.